# MacBook 13" Mid 2012 shuts down with 20% with new battery

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, software

I have this problem with my MacBook: when I turn it on, the battery reports 0%.
After replacing the battery, I've the same problem. 
New battery  has 4 cycles and 100% of charge capacity.

I have already tried SMC reset.

Is it a possible High Sierra problem? Has anyone solved it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already tried Smc reset

Comment: Is it an original battery?

Comment: No, Is a NuPower battery

Comment: Then you may have the reason right there. Contact the seller to have them fix it

Comment: I tagged this as a dupe because the OS has nothing to do with how much charge your battery has.  The OS shuts down the computer because the SMC has told it, it's running low on power.   Why?  You have bad cells.  It's a new battery, yes... It's just defective.  Get a replacement.

Comment: @girdesgo https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/236725?lq=1 see these too.. Ping people using @ to notify them of your comments

Comment: Thanks you. I have already replaced the battery twice